# Unable to fetch the data of a column with radio buttons in jsp using servlet with request.getParameterValues() function

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a table with 3 columns.Last column has 4 radio buttons in each row.I am not able to fetch all the values of radio buttons checked after submitting the form.I always get only one value which is the value of radio button checked in the first row.

Here is the code of jsp page:

```html
<form action = "SaveData" method = "POST" target = "_blank">

<h1>LIST</h1>
<%
try {
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine
name, port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and 
database name is student. */
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample";
// declare a connection by using Connection interface
Connection connection = null;
/* declare object of Statement interface that is used for executing sql 
statements. */
Statement statement = null;
// declare a resultset that uses as a table for output data from tha table.
ResultSet rs = null;
// Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters 
of string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database.*/
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "password");
/* createStatement() is used for create statement object that is used for 
sending sql statements to the specified database. */
statement = connection.createStatement();
// sql query to retrieve values from the secified table.
String QueryString = "SELECT * from data";
rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
%>
<table class="comparison-table">

<tr>
<th>LIST</th>
<th>Y/N</th>
<th>OPTIONS</th>
</tr>

<div>
<tr>
<%
while (rs.next()) {
String slist=rs.getString(1);
%>
<td name="list"><%= slist%></td>
<td>
<select id="choose" name="choose">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<form>
 <input type="radio" name="option" value="a" checked> A
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="b" >B
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="c" > C
<input type="radio"  name="option" value="d"> D
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
 
<% } %>


<%
// close all the connections.
rs.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
}
 catch (Exception ex) {
%>

<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database."+ex);
}
%>
</table>
<button value="Submit" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the Servlet code:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

//Extend HttpServlet class
@WebServlet("/SaveData")
public class SaveData extends HttpServlet {

 // Method to handle GET method request.
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {


   // Set response content type
   response.setContentType("text/html");

   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   String title = "Reading All Form Parameters";
   String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " + 
"transitional//en\">\n";

   out.println(docType +
      "<html>\n" +
      "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
      "<body bgcolor = \"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
      "<h1 align = \"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
      "<table width = \"100%\" border = \"1\" align = \"center\">\n" +
      "<tr bgcolor = \"#949494\">\n" +
         "<th>Param Name</th>"+
         "<th>Param Value(s)</th>\n"+
      "</tr>\n"
   );

   Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

   while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
       out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n<td>");
      String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

      // Read single valued data
      if (paramValues.length == 1) {
         String paramValue = paramValues[0];
         if (paramValue.length() == 0)
            out.println("<i>No Value</i>");
            else
            out.println(paramValue);
      } else {
         // Read multiple valued data
         out.println("<ul>");

         for(int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
            out.println("<li>" + paramValues[i]);
         }
         out.println("</ul>");
      }
   } 
    out.println("</tr>\n</table>\n</body></html>");

}

}
```

Output after submitting the form would be values of two parameters "choose" and "option". I get proper output for "choose" parameter ie. all the selected Yes/No options in a cloumn,whereas for "option" parameter i would get only the value of first row selected radio button ie if i select 'c' in the first row radio buttons  only 'c' will be displayed with rest of the rows ignored.

Please help me out in fetching data of all the columns of the radio buttons selected in a String array.

I also want to fetch the value of "slist" which is from database using servlet. This is under td tag with name="list".

Answer (score 0):

First you sould not nest `form` tag, remove the `form` tag before radio button.

From [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) :

> elements of type radio are generally used in radio
>   groups—collections of radio buttons describing a set of related
>   options. Only one radio button in a given group can be selected at the
>   same time.

You should add a variable to differentiate lines like this for example :

```
<tr>
  <%! int lineNumber = 0 %> 
  <%
    while (rs.next()) {
    String slist=rs.getString(1);
  %>
  <td name="list"><%= slist%></td>
  <td>
    <select id="choose" name="choose">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="option<%= lineNumber %>" value="a" checked> A
    <input type="radio" name="option<%= lineNumber %>" value="b" >B
    <input type="radio" name="option<%= lineNumber %>" value="c" > C
    <input type="radio" name="option<%= lineNumber %>" value="d"> D
  </td>
</tr>
<% lineNumber++ %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This logic worked.Got the output as expected :)